# What if I call GetProps immediately after SetProps in MAPI?

Tags: outlook, mapi

I have a question in MAPI.

If I invoke SetProps for a property, then without invoking the SaveChanges function, I invoke GetProps immediately for that property, what will happen?

Based on my own test, it seems that GetProps will get the proper property value even without SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that just fine. `SaveChanges` only kicks in some property validation - e.g. if you set plain text `PR_BODY`, `SaveChanges` will update RTF and HTML body for HTML/RTF aware stores. `SaveChanges` will also populate `PR_DISPLAY_TO/CC/BCC` properties based on the recipient table (if you updated recipients).

Other than that, `GetProps` will return the same properties set with `SetProps` without having to call `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the property value returned back when you deal with the same object instance cached in Outlook. But if you try to get another instance of the source object and get the property value, you will not get anything because the `SaveChanges` method was not called to submit changes to the store.

Comment: Yes, I use the same object instance for SetProps and GetProps